# Docker compose hot reloading does not work with vuejs app

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I have a little vueJS app runnig on docker.
When i run the app via `yarn serve` it runs fine, also it does in docker.

My problem is hot reloading will not work.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @vue/cli -g

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

  services:

    client:
      container_name: client
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - '.:/app'
        - '/app/node_modules'
      ports:
        - '8082:8080'
```

Does anyone can see the mistake i did?

Comment: what is the port using for vuejs app ? Also, use the same port every where like `8080`

Comment: the default port 8080

Comment: use this  and try `ports:
        - '8080:8080'
`

Comment: tried this at first, but it does not work

Comment: Which host os you are using?

Comment: Actually it's Windows 10, but it need it to run on my mac as well

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution:
I added the following to my compose file:

```
environment: 
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Answer (score 6):

What has worked for me in the past is to use this in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: vuejs.Dockerfile
    # command to start the development server
    command: npm run serve
    # ------------------ #
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules # <---- this enables a much faster start/reload
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment: 
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true # <---- this enables the hot reloading
```

Comment: Could you explain why adding node_modules as a volume enhance the velocity of start and reload ? I'm interested in the explanation.

Comment: I have the same question, since this anonymous volume is there in order not to be over-written from the node_modules of the project when it's copied to the container.

Comment: It has been working for me up to now but it is no longer working on my Windows machine, while it still does on my Linux one... :shrug:

Comment: it says `npm command not found`

Comment: @Sohail you should use the command that you use to start a development server, which is described in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

Also expose 8080 port

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

EXPOSE 8080 # add this line in docker file.

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @vue/cli -g

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Docker compose as

```
version: '3.7'

  services:

    client:
      container_name: client
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - '.:/app'
        - '/app/node_modules'
      ports:
        - '8080:8080'
```

server will be running in localhost:8080

Comment: `Does not work` is not an accurate description of a problem your are trying to fix. What does `docker-compose logs` says? Which command exactly are you issuing to "hot reload"? Is there any relevant output when you issue it? What happens if your replace `npm` in your docker file by `yarn` you used for your manual tests? What is the symptom making you think the application is totally down? Can you load anything in your browser or do you get a connection refused? Does it serves pages on first run then stops when your ''hot reload"?....

Comment: It works also without explicitely exposing port 8080 in the Dockerfile. Mentioning the port in the docker-compose file seems to be enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers above suggests setting an environment variable for the chokidar polling.  According to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/378) you can set the polling options to true in vue.config.js.

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      // https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/378
      watchOptions: {
        poll: true,
      },
    },
  }
};
```

Additionally, make sure that the volume you are mounting is correct as per your working dir, etc. to ensure that the files are watched correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the working on Windows + Docker Desktop. After switching to WSL2 + Docker Desktop the hot reload worked again without needed to do additionally work / variables.